# Detecção precisa de tons de pele em tempo real sob variações de iluminação

Tags: python, opencv

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que visa recomendar produtos de maquiagem adequados ao tom de pele do usuário em tempo real. O objetivo é usar a câmera do dispositivo para capturar o tom de pele do usuário e, em seguida, sugerir produtos de maquiagem compatíveis com esse tom.

Atualmente, estou usando Python e a biblioteca OpenCV para capturar o vídeo da câmera e determinar o tom de pele em tempo real com base nos valores RGB. No entanto, estou enfrentando desafios na implementação dessa recomendação, pois a precisão na captura do tom de pele não está atendendo às minhas expectativas.

Mais especificamente, estou capturando o tom de pele em RGB e comparando-o com os tons de maquiagem em RGB, mas o retorno do tom de pele não está tão preciso quanto eu gostaria.

Minha pergunta é a seguinte:

Como posso melhorar a precisão na detecção do tom de pele em tempo real usando valores RGB? Existem técnicas ou algoritmos que podem ser aplicados para tornar essa correspondência de tons de pele mais precisa?

Comment: Nunca [duplique postagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/586982/70), procure editar a original conforme orientado no quadro de fechamento. Mais detalhes na [help] e links lá contidos. Para evitar descentralização de informações o espaço de comentários foi desativado nesta postagem, mas pode ser usado na [sua pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/586982/70).